# como solucionar = python3 error, a bytes-like object is required, nor str

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

He revisado bastante el código y no se en que puede fallar, he probado con poner decode y b pero no me ha servido, he recurrido ya a foro, ¿alguien podría decirme que está mal? el error que aparece es " a bytes-like object is required, not str"

```py
import socket
class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print ("[+]Esperando las conexiones")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print(" [+]Tenemos una conexion de" + str(address))

    def ejecutar_remoto(self, command,):
        self.connection.send(command)
        return self.connection.recv(1024)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input ("shell>>")
            result = self.ejecutar_remoto(command)
            print(result)

escuchar = Listener("iria la ip", puerto)
escuchar.run()
```

Comment: `self.ejecutar_remoto(command.encode("UTF-8"))`

Comment: encantado me ayudastes, aunque ahora en la linea 24 y 20 aparece error "takes 1 positional argument but  2were guiven" pero gracias

Comment: Pensé que preguntabas sólo por ese error, no por todos los errores del código.

Comment: ya, perdón, pero hasta que no le di a iniciar no aparecieron los siguientes errores, si gustas ¿podría decirme todos los errores? ya veo que Python 3 es mas lejano a Python 2 de lo que pensaba

Comment: hay una coma `,` extra al final de los parametros de la funcion `ejecutar_remoto`

Comment: gracias, puedes visualizar mas errores?, hago todo lo dicho y me sale error tuberia rota.. y en los modulos de: `escuchar.run()`, ` result = self.ejecutar_remoto(command.encode("UTF-8"))` y `